# Angular API call is not hitting in controller method

Tags: c#, angular

I am not able to hit my controller method Get.

I have **register.component.ts** file in this I am calling dataservice's getfeed method:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dataservice.getFeed('register').subscribe(result => {
}
```

in the **data.service.ts** file, I have written like:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getFeed(methodName: string): Observable<any> {

return this.http.get(environment.baseApiUrl + methodName);
}
}
```

In My **environment.ts** file I have:

```
 baseApiUrl:'http://localhost:4200/api/'
```

And finally in **RegisterController.cs** I coded like:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RegisterController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 500)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
    }
}
```

But this Get is not hitting no way. I tried different URL directly from browser, but nothing is hitting in that get method. Any idea what I am missing in my implementation?

And in my **Startup.cs** file i have something like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller}/{action=index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Are you getting the CORS issue?

Comment: how do i check it?

Comment: is `register` in `register.component.ts` a variable with value of string `'register'`? Right now you call `this.dataservice.getFeed(register)`, did you mean to pass it as a string `this.dataservice.getFeed('register')`? Also what port is the api running in development? You are pointing the http request to port 4200 which is where angular in development runs, wouldn't it need to be pointed to the port of the api?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky its string...

Comment: @NithinPaul Check developer console on your web browser to see if there are any error or CORS issue.

Comment: @RahulSharma I am not seeing any such errors, but Alexande made a point which is worth to check, let me check that and will update

Comment: Your controller is located at `http://localhost:4200/register`, not at `http://localhost:420/api/register`.

Comment: Assuming they are using `@angular/cli`, they couldn't angular dev running on the same port as the server.

Comment: @RahulSharma now i am seeing CORS issue like you said in my developer console. Do you know what to do next?

Comment: @NithinPaul Please see my answer to enable `CORS` in your project globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to resolve your `CORS` issue, you can do the following in your `web.config` file:

Under `<system.webServer>` section, place the following to enable `CORS` globally in your project:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Rahul in my web.config i have specified this like <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders></system.webServer>

But still i am getting this same error

Comment: When i try using direct URL i am able to hit my service api method, but when i call it using angular i am not. Do i need to do anything in client angualr side?

Comment: @NithinPaul No you do not need to do anything on client side.Maybe you need to restart your IIS for the changes to reflect.

Comment: Ok also do i need to remove this <handlers> tag from <system.webServer> section? Because in my cors error its showing like it does not have ok status, so when i googled it its mentioned by someone

Comment: @NithinPaul Add this line: `<add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />` in your `<handlers>` section and then try

Comment: Rahul now its getting hit in my service side :), i removed that handler section completely Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @NithinPaul Always glad to help.Cheers.

Comment: When i host this site, will this usage <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> cause any security risks, Also is will this CORS error popup  again?

Comment: @NithinPaul It depends on your application and its usage. You need to understand what `CORS` is. You can read more on: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-cors-in-asp-net-webapi-2/#:~:text=CORS%20stands%20for%20Cross%2DOrigin,scripts%2C%20iframes%2C%20and%20videos.

Answer (score 1):

If I unterstand you correctly, you want to call the api controller `http://localhost:4200/api/register`.

In order to do this make the following:

1. Change your controller code like this:

   ```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class RegisterController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("register")]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 500)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
        }
    }
   ```
2. Get rid of the localhost and port number, you won't need it:

   ```
    baseApiUrl:'api/'
   ```

Your `getFeed` method shoud look like this without parameter:

```
getFeed: Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('api/register');
}
```

Or, I think, it should work too if you just change the `baseApiUrl` like above. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Today, make example
if controller do not work - check proxy.conf.js, if you have 404 error

```
   const PROXY_CONFIG = [
     {
          context: [
          "/weatherforecast",
           "/salary",
           "/data",
      ],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).